# New requirements for Americans traveling to Cuba

Tags: visas, cuba

Hi everyone this is my first time on this site so I apologize in advance for any mistakes in my question.

I am a US citizen who is going to Cuba in January.

Is it true that I can travel under a "general license" without applying for government permission? What verification do I need that my trip meets one of the approved categories, if any?

On the Cuban side, what is the best / cheapest way to get a tourist card? Can I get one at the airport?

(My itinerary is PIT-FLL-HAV on Southwest, if that helps)

Comment: https://www.southwest.com/html/promotions/new-service-cuba.html